# Loading gif only works on firefox, but freezes on other browsers after setTimeout(jquery)

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, loading, gif

I want to display a loading gif when I call a certain function and hide it when I call another. I managed to do this just fine on firefox, but the loading gif freezes on IE and on chrome.

The function I call is one that loads a new window with a pdf, here is the jquery code:

```
 function newPage(){
     $('#loader').show();
     setTimeout(LoadPDF,100);
 }   

 function ChangeLoad(){
     $('#loader').hide();
}
```

And here's the css:

```
#loader {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('imagens/spinner.gif') center center no-repeat rgba( 255, 255, 255, .6 );
    Display:Block;
}
```

It works until the timeout is met(so if I put x amount of time instead of 100 on the setTimeout, it will freeze after this x amount of time). I've tried some solutions but none of them worked, keep in mind I don't want to use ajax in this(I've seen a lot of solutions about ajax, I'm not even sure it could apply here).

So is there anyway to make the gif work on all browsers? I'm kind noob on this, but I searched a lot before asking. I tried to make them both synchronous(loading gif and the LoadPDF function), but it didn't work(maybe I didn't do it correctly).

BTW, sorry if my english is bad.

**Update:** One thing I found out is that the gif only stops when doing something on the server, here we use intersystems cache, so basically it stops when executing stuff on this server. Do you guys know anyway for me to do this?

Comment: Does `LoadPDF` internally call ajax synchronous? Or do you have a `ajaxSetup()` somewhere that sets ajax to synchronous?

Comment: `"D"` and `"B"` at `Display:Block` should be lowercase characters

Comment: @mpf82 No, it's just a javascript function that executes a method that uses cache object script to generate a pdf, and then open this pdf in a new window with window.open.